# How to exclude hidden element from yadcf column(search) filter?

Tags: javascript, yadcf

I'm using **yadcf filter plugin** and the code is as follows...

**HTML:**

```
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>xyz</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span>
          <span id="eg1">abc</span>
          <span id="eg2" style="display: none;">fgd abc wew</span>
        </span>  
      </td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span>
          <span id="eg3">wew</span>
          <span id="eg4" style="display: none;">fgd abc wew</span>
        </span>  
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Here,** I want to exclude span element(hidden) having Id of "eg2" and "eg4" from the column filter of yadcf. But whenever I choose an option from select2 it gives me both row as the same text is there in the hidden element.

My JS is as below..

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    let dataTable = $('#myTable').DataTable();
    yadcf.init(dataTable, [{
        column_number: 0,
        filter_type: 'multi_select',
        select_type: 'select2',
        column_data_type: 'html',
        html_data_type: 'selector',
        html_data_selector: 'span:eq(0)',
    }], );  
});
```

**How can I exclude hidden elements from yadcf column(search) filter?**
I couldn't get the way how to do it. Please help. Thanks in advance.

**JSFIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/vjmvj/w5dbtczo/28/

Comment: What if you use column_data_type as rendered_html?

Comment: I used it as well. But, it doesn't work.

Comment: please provde a minimal jsfiddle example page so I can try and help

Comment: @Daniel Hello, This is my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vjmvj/w5dbtczo/28/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answer Continued...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63544497/how-to-exclude-hidden-element-from-yadcf-columnsearch-filter/63563046#63563046)

This is my custom function

```js
function multiSelectCustomFilterFunction(filterVal, columnVal) {
    const item = columnVal.trim().split(/[ \t]{5,}/g)[0]; // To select first inner span tag which is visible
    filterValArray = [];
    filterVal.forEach(trimmer);
    function trimmer(value) {
        filterValArray.push(value.trim()); // To remove extra space around values
    }
    return filterValArray.length != 0 ? filterValArray.includes(item.trim()) : true ; // To match selected and available data 
}
```

**JSFIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/vjmvj/w5dbtczo/37/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `filter_type: 'multi_select_custom_func'` (you still need to apply your logic)

[Read the docs](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/93d57ef7245bef47191584996dee84637080b809/src/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L43)

See example code

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    let dataTable = $('#myTable').DataTable();
    yadcf.init(dataTable, [{
            column_number: 0,
        filter_type: 'multi_select_custom_func',
        custom_func: myCustomFilterFunction,
        select_type: 'select2',
        column_data_type: 'html',
        html_data_type: 'selector',
        html_data_selector: 'span:eq(0)'
    }], );
    
    function myCustomFilterFunction(filterVal, columnVal, rowValues, stateVal) {
        //apply logic here
        console.log(columnVal);
        console.log(stateVal);
    }
});
```

See it working (you still need to apply your own logic) https://jsfiddle.net/vedmack/kw1aophg/

Comment: Yes.. Thanks, i did the same!